# What is the best way to generatej uuid in java for neo4j nodes

Tags: java, neo4j

Neo4j does not recommend to use node id to store in third party system for later referencing.

1. So what is best ways to generate uuid in java for neo4j nodes?
2. Currently I'm using UUID.randomUUID(); to generate uuid. Is there any performance impact for neo4j search if I use UUID.randomUUID()?

Comment: This seems like a tool/framework recommendation question. What you use is entirely up to your preference (assuming you even need one), and I doubt the generation of a UUID is going to have anywhere near the operation cost as a database call.

Answer (score 7):

Now Cypher has a `randomUUID` native function, see https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/scalar/#functions-randomuuid

> The function randomUUID() returns a randomly-generated Universally Unique Identifier (UUID), also known as a Globally Unique Identifier (GUID). This is a 128-bit value with strong guarantees of uniqueness.

Example:

```
RETURN randomUUID() AS uuid
```

Answer (score 5):

It is true that you should not reference an internal id in an external system as internal ids are not stable.

One option for generating a UUID would be using the [`apoc.create.uuid`](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_creating_data) function available in the [apoc procedure library](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures). For example:

```
CREATE (p:Person)
SET p.name = "Bob",
    p.uuid = apoc.create.uuid()
```

See [this blog post](https://neo4j.com/blog/intro-user-defined-procedures-apoc/) for more information on user defined procedures and functions.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to to use GraphAware UUID to assign UUIDs to nodes and optionally relationships, transparently. It will also make sure that the UUIDs are not changed or deleted.

https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-uuid

Disclaimer: I work at GraphAware

Comment: @Luanna I have tried your suggestion and seems it generate string based uuid. Is there any performance impact in terms of searching and indexing using string based uuid rather than number based uuid?